# How to interpret this graph function algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, loops, graph, tree

So I have a G directed graph (directed in both ways from a node v), and its Euler tour labelling, like this:

[image: Eulerian tree tour labelling of graph G]

I have a function, called `root(written_L,u)`, where `u` is the new root of the target graph/component, and `written_L` is an Euler tour labelling. So the root function makes the u node the root, and recalculates all the edge labels, giving a new Euler tour labelling.

However, I can't totally understand the algorithm given for the root function:

[image: root function description]

And the corresponding denotement system:

[image]

I tried to make a program for this problem, but I couldn't totally understand these mathematical expressions. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me all these meanings in a non-mathematical form.
Furthermore, feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes all you need is an example. The image below shows the edge labelling after moving the root node to the middle of the center column.

[image]

You'll notice that all we did is subtract 5 from all the numbers. That's great when the original label is at least 5. When the original label is less than 5, we need to subtract 5 and then add 12, to keep the label in the range 0 to 11.

So for example, the edge that used to be labelled 8 is relabelled as `8-5=3`. And the edge that was labelled 4 is relabelled as `4 -5+12 = 11`.

The other thing you need to know is that subtracting 5 (keeping the result in the range 0 to 11) is the same as adding 7 modulo 12. Repeating the same examples, 8 is relabelled `(8+7) % 12 = 3`, and 4 is relabelled `(4+7) % 12 = 11`.

So the algorithm is:

- Find the largest label entering the original root, and add 1 to find the modulo (M). In the example the largest label is 11, so M is 12.
- Find the smallest label leaving the new root (Z). In the example Z is 5.
- Compute the delta (D) as `D = M - Z`. In the example, D is 7.
- Update every label (L) using the formula `newL = (L+D) % M`

Comment: Wow, great explanation, thank you so much! I understand your solution and now i can interpret those ugly letters. Howewer, i have a bit of uncertainty regarding the two for each in the image: So as far as i get the first for each, it iterates over every L(w,v) edge in T(u), and 'shiftes' them by `newRootSmallestOutEdge mod oldRootLargestInEdge+1`. So basically this first for-each sets every edge for its new value. Hence i don't know what the second for each exactly do. Sets every smallest outgoing edge label in every node?

Comment: @NeverSayEver The math in the question is describing an algorithm for a forest (of many trees). But the example in the question and this answer is a single tree.